# polynomial regression model in python

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, statsmodels

As I understood, Regression equation can be calculated by this functions:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
fg = smf.ols(formula='X ~ Y', data=data).fit()
```

we can also calculate from numpy polyfit function.

```
numpy.polyfit(x, y, degree)
```

as we can change the degree in numpy polyfit.

In ols function we can also add other independent variables  as given below:

```
fg = smf.ols(formula='X ~ Y+Y1+Y2', data=data).fit()
```

So my question can we change the order/degree of fit in ols function ? 
or can we add another independent variables in numpy polyfit function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of the statsmodels ability that you mention, formulae are specified using the patsy language (see http://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Thus, for instance, that first invocation that you used could instead have been the following.

```
fg = smf.ols(formula='X ~ Y + Y**2', data=data).fit()
```

or

```
fg = smf.ols(formula='X ~ log(Y)', data=data).fit()
```

Comment: So we cant add another  independent variables in ols? am I correct?. If I want to change order from 1 to 2 or 3.

Comment: Sure, you can. See http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/example_formulas.html. I intended to ask, what do you mean by order?

Comment: I mean order (or degree) 1 is for linear, order 2 is for Quadratic, order 3 is Cubic and so on..

Comment: Yes, you could have, for example: `X ~ Y1**2 + Y2 + Y3**2`.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand..so here: X ~ Y1**2 + Y2 + Y3**2 means  Y1, Y2 and Y3 are three independent  variables with 2degree polynomial function with X?

Comment: Y1, Y2, Y3 are the independent variables. X is a linear function of Y2, and a quadratic function of each of the other variables.

Comment: Thank you :) Now I understand.